# JS окно ввода, кнопка добавления, удаления и окно вывода

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать окно ввода куда соответсвенно можно вводить информацию, окно вывода где будет выводится эта информация, кнопку добавления соответсвенно и кнопку удаления.

Учу я джава скрип на работе, на которой запрещено пользоваться всем кроме блокнота, и пишу я код в блокноте, собирая и пытясь разобраться что такое JS и с чем его едят.
Так что код очень простой.

Кусок кода с кнопками нашел немного адаптировал под себя, но **не могу никак сделать кнопку удаления чтобы она работала.**

Если можно как-то оптимизировать код, для кнопки добавления (или изменения функции или вообще оптимизации) то пиши я буду рад, только с пояснениями как для чайника. Потому что я реально хочу разобраться и уйти из этого АДА.

Заранее благодарю вас.

Код ниже.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div  id="printBlock" class="sub2">
</div>


<form name="search">

    <input type="text" name="inputWindow" placeholder="Введите букву"></input>
    <input type="button" name="print" value="Ввод" />
     
    <input type="button" name="delete" value="Del" />

</form>


<script>

function printForm(){
     
    // получаем значение поля inputWindow
    let inputWindowBox = document.search.inputWindow;
    let value = inputWindowBox.value;

    // получаем элемент printBlock
    let printBlock = document.getElementById("printBlock");

    // создаем новый параграф
    let pElement = document.createElement("p");

    // устанавливаем у него текст
    pElement.textContent = value;

    // добавляем параграф в printBlock
    printBlock.appendChild(pElement);
}
 
let printButton = document.search.print;
printButton.addEventListener("click", printForm);


</script>

<style>


.sub2
{
display:inline-block;
background:#21a23e;
border: 1px solid #000222;
 
}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переписал ваш вариант.
Теперь по порядку, что использовалось:

1. [Обработчик события](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events)
2. [Поиск элемента](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom)
3. [Вставка элементов](https://learn.javascript.ru/multi-insert)
4. [Навигация по дереву элементов](https://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom)

Также добавил комментарии, чтобы было более понятнее, что происходит.

```js
// Сначала получим все используемые элементы.

//Получаем инпут
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
//Получаем кнопку "Ввод"
const enterBtn = document.querySelector('#enter');
//Получаем кнопку "Del"
const delBtn = document.querySelector('#del');
//Получаем блок в который будем добавлять
const printBlock = document.querySelector('#printBlock');

//Повесим обработчик нажатия на кнопку "Ввод"
enterBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //При нажатии, получим значение из инпута
  const value = input.value;
  //Затем, создадим новый элемент и сразу запишем в него наше значение
  printBlock.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<p>${value}</p>`)
})

//Повесим обработчик нажатия на кнопку "Del"
delBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //Получим всем "детей" из нашего блока для данных
  const childrens = printBlock.children;
  //Проверим, а есть ли в нем вообще "дети"?
  if (childrens.length > 0) {
    //Если есть, то удаляем последнего
    childrens[childrens.length - 1].remove();
  }
})
```

```css
.sub2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #21a23e;
  border: 1px solid #000222;
}
```

```html
<div id="printBlock" class="sub2"></div>

<form name="search">
  <input type="text" id='input' name="inputWindow" placeholder="Введите букву" />

  <input type="button" id='enter' name="print" value="Ввод" />
  <input type="button" id='del' name="delete" value="Del" />
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Рад был помочь)